Use ggplot2 to loop through multiple plots and add a table
I am trying to produce a large volume of plots with data tables underneath. The plot will contain an individual store's sales by year for two different products. I also need a table underneath containing information not in the plot - total revenue for the whole period of time and predicted sales for next year. This information is currently in a separate data frame. I am attempting to produce one plot/table combo per page for a large volume of stores.
I have been able to produce the plot I want for a single store using the following:
Reproducible data:
sales <- data.frame(Year=c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019), 
                        Store_Number=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                        Sales=c(200, 250, 50, 150, 200, 75, 100, 450, 150, 150, 200, 175), 
                        Product=c("Pizza", "Salad", "Pizza", "Salad", "Pizza", "Salad", "Pizza", "Salad", "Pizza", "Salad", "Pizza", "Salad"))
projected <- data.frame(Store_Number=c(1,2,3), 
                        TotalSales=c(1000,500,650),
                        FutureSales=c(1000,600,400))  

Plot:
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

plot <- sales %>%
  filter(Store_Number == 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Sales, linetype = Product, 
             color = Product, shape = Product)) +
  geom_point(size=1.5) + geom_line(size=.75) + theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Sales") +
  ggtitle("Store Number 1") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#FC4E07"))

plot

table <- projected %>% filter(Store_Number == 1) %>%  select(-1)

mytheme <- gridExtra::ttheme_default(
  core = list(padding = unit(c(2.5, 2.5), "mm")))
tbl <- tableGrob(table, theme = mytheme, rows = NULL)

grid.arrange(plot, tbl, nrow = 2, as.table = TRUE, heights = c(4,1))


I have also been able to produce just the chart portion for all my stores (with no table) using the following:
store_plot <- function(store_of_interest) {
  sales %>%
    filter(Store_Number == store_of_interest) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Sales, linetype = Product, 
             color = Product, shape = Product)) +
  geom_point(size=1.5) + geom_line(size=.75) + theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Sales") +
  ggtitle(store_of_interest) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#FC4E07"))
}

plot_list <- map(unique(sales$Store_Number), store_plot)
plot_list

I tried adding the table, but using this code I get an error that only 'grobs' allowed in "gList":
store_table <- function(store_of_interest) {
  projected %>%
    filter(Store_Number == store_of_interest)
  grid.table(projected, theme = mytheme, rows = NULL)
}

table_list <- map(unique(projected$Store_Number), store_table)

grid.arrange(plot_list, table_list, nrow = 2, as.table = TRUE, heights = c(4,1))

Can anyone suggest how I can alter this to include the data table recursively as I've done with the line chart?

You need to use tableGrob in your store_table function (not grid.table) and pass the filtered projected dataset to the function (see the . and the extra %>%).
Then, you need to loop through your previously created plots and the tables that we just created and put them together:
store_plot <- function(store_of_interest) {
  sales %>%
    filter(Store_Number == store_of_interest) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Sales, linetype = Product, 
               color = Product, shape = Product)) +
    geom_point(size=1.5) + geom_line(linewidth=.75) + theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    labs(x = "Year", y = "Sales") +
    ggtitle(store_of_interest) + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#FC4E07"))
}


mytheme <- gridExtra::ttheme_default(
  core = list(padding = unit(c(2.5, 2.5), "mm")))
store_table <- function(store_of_interest) {
    projected %>%
      filter(Store_Number == store_of_interest) %>% 
    tableGrob(., theme = mytheme, rows = NULL)
  }

plot_list <- map(unique(sales$Store_Number), store_plot)
table_list <- map(unique(projected$Store_Number), store_table)

lapply(1:length(table_list), \(i) 
       grid.arrange(plot_list[[i]], table_list[[i]], 
                    nrow = 2, as.table = TRUE, heights = c(4,1)))


Created on 2024-06-06 with reprex v2.0.2
